# FluentValidation occures even on models that do not have any validators set

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I am using FluentValidation with MVC 3.0; I have configured it to work with a custom validator factory and an IoC container (Unity);

Everything works fine and i am able to do custom validations and inject them with my dependencies... however a strange thing has occurred: on all strongly typed views on which i have HtmlHelper created controls (ex: Html.Editor), it seems that MVC is trying to instantiate a validator, and this causes a Unity error because there is no Validator mapped in Unity for those models... in those views i don't have any checks to see if Model is valid, and also don't have any automatic model binding, so how can i stop this from happening? i don't want to have to create empty validators for each model and register them in Unity just to get rid of these errors..

Here is how i register the factory in global.asax:

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider =>
{
    provider.ValidatorFactory = new UnityValidatorFactory(container);
});
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

and this is how i register my custom validators:

```
container.RegisterType<IValidator<XViewModel>, XViewModel>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(container.Resolve<ILocalizationService>(),
    container.Resolve<ISessionService>()));
```

For the XView, everything is ok, and in my action method i do a TryUpdateModel and validation is working fine; but for other views where i do not want to have any validation, MVC still tries to resolve the validator for them and normally fails because nothing is registered in Unity

Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

Thank you,

George

**edit:**
the errors for other views are: 
The current type, IValidator`1[...ViewModel], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I modified my UnityValidatorFactory to return null when the type could not be resolved; i don't know how good this workaround is from performance point of view (since an exception is raised) but for the moment i don't have a better solution...